# Fresnel equations of reflection applied to microparticles

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection, wavelength

I wanted to know if the Fresnel equations of reflection, as [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations), can be used to calculate the reflectance on the interface of particles which have a diameter near the size of the wavelength of the light. (i.e. the size parameter $x$ = 2 $\pi$ n medium radius/$\lambda$ is equal to 5, 1, 0.1 or less)

I am familiar with [Mie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering) and [Rayleigh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) scattering, but I am just interested in the reflectance at the surface of such a small particle. I want to quantify what amount of incident light energy enters the particle (this is for a coating application)